# Python 2.7, unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python-2.7

I am a newbie to Python and I was trying my hand at the following problem:  I want to add numbers entered by the user.  Here is my program

```
add = 0  
num = input('Enter a number:')
add = add + num
while num != ' ' : 
    num = input('Next number:')
    add = add + num
    print add
```

I want to terminate the program when a blank is entered. So I know the problem is with line 4.  What would be the correct syntax?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 3):

In python 2.7 user input should be processed using [`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

This is because [`input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) is semantically equivalent to:

```
eval(raw_input(prompt))
```

which, when given an empty string, will cause the following line of code:

```
eval('')
```

will return an `EOF` error while parsing, since empty is not a valid object to parse.

Since `raw_string` doesnt parse the string into an int you'll also have to use `int()` to convert it when you do the addition.
You also need to change to while statement:

```
add = 0  
num = raw_input('Enter a number:')
# you cant do a + here what if the user hits enter right away.
if num:
    add = int(num)

while num: # enter will result in a null string not a space
    num = raw_input('Next number:')
    if num:
        add = add + int(num)
    print add
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following and read a bit.

```
>>> help(input)

>>> help(raw_input)

>>> s=raw_input()
<return right here>
>>> s
''
>>> s=raw_input()
 <one space followed by return here>
>>> s
' '
>>>
```